# Doughnut Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_listened') and TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_labels')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

So, as I get main problem is chart try to use labels form undefined object and can't find them - after that it gives error exception.

Also good question why it happens only when I reload the page and work when I go on page with chart from other page (render content before)

```
<Doughnut
    data={
        {
            labels: chartsData.labels || [''],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: chartsData.data || [],
                    backgroundColor: colors || [],
                    borderColor: colors || [],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                },

            ],
        }
    }
    options={{
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            datalabels: {
                display: false
            },
        }
    }}
/>
```

I try to contain all fields with full data, also when it gives null / [] from server, but it also doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question probably needs more code, at least routines that are calling this one or using this dataset. And usually it is better to post the important parts of the error message.

Comment: The error messages might indicate that `plugin-chartjs-datalabels` is misconfigured. Since you are not displaying datalabels anyway, you may try removing the plugin. And if it solves your problem then try to install it again in a proper way. In any case, we should not provide guesses, but answers, and for that we need to debug a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which in the case of a react application might come as a stackblitz, codesandbox or similar.